# How to do one image file, save and delete functions continously in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, file-io

How to do one image file, save and delete functions continously in C# 4.0

i am looking to modify an image file like rotate 90 degree. first i have saved aternative name and delete the original file and rename the alternate filename to original file name.

here after hosting my application in iis, faced this error message 
"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

```
Image i= Image.FromFile(fileName);
i.Save(svfilename);
System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
System.IO.File.Move(svfilename, fileName);
```

Comment: Why don't you simply overwrite the existing file, instead of using a temp file? `Image i= Image.FromFile(fileName); ProcessSomething(i);
i.Save(fileName,ImageFormat.PNG);`. Please note that you also missed the ImageFormat parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You used the `Image.FromFile` method to create an `Image` object representing the image contained in that file

```
Image i= Image.FromFile(fileName);
```

That's why you cannot delete the file: because your process is still using it! You won't be able to delete the file on disk until the `Image` object you created from it is disposed, freeing the lock on the file.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx) for the `FromFile` method confirms this:

> The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.

To ensure that an object is disposed, wrap its creation and use inside of a [`using` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be like this

```
Image i= Image.FromFile(fileName);
i.Save(svfilename);
i.Dispose();
System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
System.IO.File.Move(svfilename, fileName);
```